# Finding Pythagorean triples

Tags: algebra-precalculus, pythagorean-triples

I've encountered the following problem in a programming textbook . Let x,y denote two real variables and k a fixed parameter (real as well) . Find (efficiently) all the possible values for x,y such that :

$x^2+y^2=k^2$.

The problem itself is easy to solve through simple lines of code, but I'm much more interested in a mathematical approach that can be translated into code without much effort.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Comment: What do you mean by "find all possible values"?  If $x$ and $y$ are real variables (as opposed to natural or rational numbers) then there are uncountably infinitely many solutions to this problem.   Perhaps you want only the *rational* solutions?

Comment: Rational indeed, I'm terribly sorry.

Comment: The ordinary meaning of *Pythagorean triple* is a sequence $(x,y,z)$ of *positive integers* such that $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how familiar with abstract algebra you are, but Hilbert's Theorem 90 provides a very elegant characterization of the rational points on the unit circle (which are precisely the  Pythagorean triples). Wikipedia has some of the details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Theorem_90).

Answer (score 0):

We can find dissimilar triples with matching hypotenuse sides, if they exist, using the function below to find the right $(m,n)$ combinations for Euclid's formula:

$$n=\sqrt{C-m^2}$$
Whenever we get integer for $n$ and $n<m$ then we have the $(m,n)$ needed to find a Pythagorean triple with a hypotenuse equal to $C$. The search is limited to where $\mathbf {\biggl\lceil\sqrt{\frac{C}{2}}\space\space\biggr\rceil\le m\le\lfloor\sqrt{C}\rfloor}$. For example, we want to find one or more triples with $C=697$. Then $m_{min}=\biggl\lceil\sqrt{\frac{697}{2}}\space\space\biggr\rceil=19\quad  m_{max}=\lfloor\sqrt{697}\rfloor=26.$

Trying different values where $m=19\text{ to }26$, we find $(21,16)\text{ and }(24,11).$

$$A=m^2-n^2\qquad B=2mn\qquad C=m^2+n^2$$
$$21^2-16^2=185\qquad2*21*16=672\qquad21^2+16^2=697$$
$$24^2-11^2=455\qquad2*24*11=528\qquad24^2+11^2=697$$
Sometimes there are no triples that match, such as if we find no integers in our search from $1\text{ to } 26.$ At other times there will be only one match or many such as in the example below.

$$(47,1104,1105)\quad(817,744,1105)\quad(943,576,1105)\quad(1073,264,1105)$$